# Bootstrap dropdown menu is not displaying

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I tried the following in my AJS app and the bootstrap dropdown menyu is not getting displayed. What could be the possible reason?

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 searchBarBG">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
     <div class="filterBarCommon" title="Filter By" 
     ng-click="searchReservationVm.closeAllFilterDiv()">
     <span>Filter By</span>
     </div>
     <span class="lineDiv" id="filterLineDiv"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
     <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You've got a button group containing a single button, is there a reason for that?

Comment: no. i can remove it. yet i am not getting the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading between the lines, I suspect that you're using the example code from the [Bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns), while trying to actually get a [Bootstrap AngularUI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown) directive working.

Make sure you're adding the `dropdown` and `dropdown-toggle` directives onto the respective parent and button elements.

```
    <span dropdown> <!-- Notice the dropdown directive here -->
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" dropdown-toggle> <!-- and the dropdown-toggle directive here --> 
        Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
       </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
        <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
          <a href>{{choice}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </span>
```

*side note: You should really try and provide more information, including what you've tried, what errors you're getting and things you'd tried, then you'd get less down-votes.*

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown requires a link to the bootstrap.js file.